# GetComponentsInChildren by name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm searching for the best way to GetComponentsInChildren by their name. The case is like this, in my GameObject I have a couple of gameobjects that all are named the same.

I want to access all of them by searching for the name and then changing the material of them. The changing material part is already done in the code further down.

```
gameobject.GetComponentInChildren<Transform>().Find(Name).GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = newMaterial;
```

The upper code worked for getting one of the gameobjects and changing the material. My question is how to get all of the gameobjects and change the material.

(There are not always the same amount of gameobjects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it now it makes little sense.

- [`GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html) returns exactly **one single** object -> the same this is called on since `GetComponentInChildren` also looks for the component on itself!
- `Find` again only returns one single object that is somewhere nested below this object.

Why even use `GetComponentInChildren<Transform>` when you later anyway rather want a `MeshRenderer` reference?

---

I think what you are trying to do is rather get all `MeshRenderer` components, then filter them by name.

```
foreach(var meshRenderer in gameobject.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>(true))
{
    if(meshRenderer.name == Name)
    {
        meshRenderer.material = newMaterial;
    }
}
```

Note the `s` in [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html) -> This returns **ALL** `MeshRenderer` references nested under this object (including this one). By passing in `true` as parameter this also includes inactive GameObjects and disabled Components.

---

You could also use [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) like

```
foreach(var meshRenderer in gameobject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>(true).Where(meshRenderer => meshRenderer.name == Name))
{
    meshRenderer.material = newMaterial;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your detailed answer! That worked, I'm wondering though if the performance gets better if you find the objects by their name instead of the meshrenderer (because now every object with a meshrenderer is being found, and that's like 20 more objects)?

Comment: Going by name (`string`) is always the most expensive way to go ;) Components are hashed and stored per scene object which is way faster to iterate. Of course the usual answer is - it depends :D but I would claim that `GetComponentsInChildren` is generally faster than iterating through all objects recursive and check their names ;)